# React-router-dom Link open at the top of page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

So I am feeling pretty dum to ask this but cannot find a straight answer to it.

Do I need to give any css parameter or directly to `<Link>` in order for the pages on my react app open at the top?

**EDIT**
So refraining, everytime I click on a `<Link>`element at my reactJs project, the Link opens a page at the middle of the screen, not a the top.

For example. I have this component

```
 <li ><Link to={{pathname: "/product", state: {products}}}><i className="fa fa-search"></i></Link></li>
```

and when I click on in, it opens a new page/component but not at the top of the page. The user needs to scroll up in order to see the top, and i would like to open new pages directly at the top!

Comment: Can you rephrase this, the question is not clear.

Comment: @DehandeCroos I edited it with a clear explanation

Comment: React-router-dom can't open at the top page, you can use `document.body.scrollTop` to go to top

Comment: try #product if its an element; or if its an page try to pase you routes code

Comment: @OblicionA if i'm not wrong, maybe you are asking how to re position a window.. right ??

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without installing any additional libraries. You can check the official example of `react-router` for scroll restoration [here](http://%20https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/scroll-restoration.md).

Comment: The correct link for [scroll restoration](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/scroll-restoration) in react-router documentation.

Comment: The current "correct" link for [scroll restoration](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.8.1/components/scroll-restoration) in the react-router documentation.

Comment: For real ? @@ I got stuck because It does not scroll to top automatically after I click in Link component

Answer (score 0):

You can use library [react-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll), and detect when change pathname of location, scroll to Top like this

```
import { animateScroll } from 'react-scroll';

useEffect(() => {
    animateScroll.scrollToTop({
      duration: 0
    });
}, [location.pathname]);
```

Answer (score 0):

make scrollToTop function and use it in your link tag

```
const scrollToTop = () => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
}
```

when user click on any link our function will make our page scroll to top.

```
 <li   onClick={scrollToTop} ><Link to={{pathname: "/product", state: {products}}}><i className="fa fa-search"></i></Link></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the class component for my react blog. The issue got solved by adding the following method and calling it inside componentDidMount().

```
scrollToTop = () => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.scrollToTop()
}
```

You can check this code is working. Live example, [Blog](https://magbanum.com/#/blog).

If you are using a function component, then same method you can use and call it inside UseEffect().

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...
I created a function that will run after 10 nano-sec, i have tried without timer and making a use effect that will depend on path, but that didn't work for me...

```
const YourComponent = () => {

  const scrollToTop = () => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      scrollToTop()
    }, 10)

    return () => clearTimeout(timerId)
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      ....
    </>
  )
}
```